# JQM Flip Toggle Switch play stop audio

Tags: jquery, mobile, switch-statement, toggle, flip

Im using Flipswitch widget in jQuery Mobile and want to play audio file when the switch is ON and stop when the switch is OFF.

My HTML code:

```
<audio id="soundtrack">
  <source src="Sounds/soundtheme.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="Sounds/soundtheme.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

    <form>
    <label for="flip-select-audio">AUDIO:</label>
    <select id="flip-select-audio" name="flip-select-audio" data-role="flipswitch">
        <option value="off">OFF</option>
        <option value="on">ON</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Im trying to figure out how the JS code could be

```
$('#flip-select-audio').change(function() {

...

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
$('#flip-select-audio').change(function() {
    var soundtrack = $("#soundtrack")[0];
    if ($(this).val() == "on") {
        soundtrack.play();
    } else {
        soundtrack.pause();
        soundtrack.currentTime = 0;
    }

});
```

**Update** : Working perfectly here https://jsfiddle.net/q3Lw8c4g/1/ You should check if your sound file is readable.

Comment: thanks but seems doesn't work, at least i tried in Chrome browser from desktop. You can test it here: http://www.theredlips.it/giochi/Sx1.html

Comment: working here : https://jsfiddle.net/q3Lw8c4g/ But I think your problem comes from flipswitch I ll update my answer when it's fixed

Comment: thanks for the working example provided! But seems doesn't work for me, i just made a test page with the code equal to your JSFiddle here http://www.theredlips.it/giochi/test.html

Comment: I checked your site, you have some weird chars line 14. Can you try to replace your weird double quotes.

Comment: uhm i deleted the blank spaces and replaced the double quotes, then checked the file with 2 editors: Notepad++ and Scintilla, now you still see the  weird chars Rogers?

Comment: You should surround your code with `$(document).ready(function() {...your code here...});` It should work now